# Giving access using username javascript code

Tags: javascript

Here I have username in session storage intially Iam blocking admission and status in navbar if session is empty, is admin or user logs in Iam storing it in session if username == admin Iam blocking status and admission is visible if user logged in still it shows admission only instud need to view status.
html

```
<a href="#" id="admission"target="_self">Admissions</a>
<a href="#" id="status"target="_self">status</a>
```

javascript

```
var n = sessionStorage.getItem("username");
  
if( n == null){
  document.getElementById("admission").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("status").style.display = "none";
 }
else if(n == "username",admin){
  document.getElementById("status").style.display = "none";
}
else{
  document.getElementById("admission").style.display="none";a
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to check your elseif condition:

```
else if(n == "username",admin){
```

should be

```
else if(n === "admin"){
```